# Load all text files to one worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel-2010

In Excel 2010 I want to load all text files data from a folder to one Worksheet.

Each sheet should have data of one text file.

Each sheet is pipe delimited with header on first Row.

## Update Macro

```
Sub LoadTextFilesLoop()
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
     'Get the folder object associated with the directory
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Export\")
     'Loop through the Files collection
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    NewFileImport (objFile.Name)
    Next
     'Clean up!
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing
End Sub

Sub NewFileImport(FileName)
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Export\FileName", _
        Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = FileName
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 65001
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

The loop is not loading the data.

I still have to figure out how I can get the Number of Columns in each file.

```
.TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1)
```

This line tells three columns in this file. This should vary based on the file columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got this worked
 here is my Macro for it.

```
Sub LoadTextFilesLoop()
Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
     'Get the folder object associated with the directory
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Export\")
     'Loop through the Files collection
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    NewFileImport (objFile.Name)
    Next
     'Clean up!
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    End Sub

Sub NewFileImport(FileName)
Dim fName As String
fName = Left(FileName, Len(FileName) - 4)
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Export\" + FileName, _
        Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = fName
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 65001
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Select
    ActiveSheet.Name = Left(fName, 31)
End Sub
```